# Spark Dataframe Join Big-O

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have been thinking about the scalability for a Spark Dataframe join command. Since the dataframes are not indexed and not necessarily in sequence, would it be fair to say the dataframe join command is O(n^2)?

I am currently taking SQL stored procedure JOIN statements and converting them into Spark SQL / Spark Dataframes and the join commands are taking much longer in Spark.

Comment: There are many factors you have to weigh in when doing a join in Spark than doing them in plain SQL. Generally, a left outter join with no indexes should take `O(m*n)` where `m` and `n` are the number of records in each table. If we're using a broadcast hash join, we can do better with `O(n+m)`. But in Spark SQL, you also take under consideration data locality, partitioning, network bandwidth, size of the dataset, etc.